# Saving Last visited pages for users

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way to save about last three visited pages for each user in his profile in my asp.net mvc website ? I want something like "www.booking.com" which shows last visited hotels for each user in his profile.

Comment: iabbott, I tried to use action filters to save pages' links but I am still new to this technology and I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert record to a table when your request new page with user id ans the page url with the date time.

In UI you can load the last 3 URLs based on user id and the inserted date time field.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
Should I use action filter to save page links ? aslo how should I deal with deletion of pages that are very old because this way table would be very big